# Should a PHP cloud storage application create a new table for each user with rows for each user files?

Tags: php, cloud, storage

Should a basic PHP cloud storage application create a new table for each user with rows for each user files?

Currently, (after log in) the application gives each user their own directory and the php loops through each file in the directory and outputs it on their dashboard. The user can then download and view their data. Should i be using a database system for user's files?

What would the benefits be of using a database for this type of application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely add some sort of abstraction layer in the form of a database for many reasons one of which being performance. When a users directory starts holding many files it will become memory expensive to read the file-system directly each time. Abstracting the contents of a directory into rows within a database table will give you speed, scalability, and a way to later on index and search your files as well as being able to title or tag files etc.

The design of your database schema can vary from application to application one might do as you said where each user gets their own table but that would be far more complex than lets say having a single table with a column specifying the owner of each file (by user ID).

Comment: I see, that makes more sense now. I didn't think about performance problems. A single table with different columns is a good idea.